# C# .NET Implement DHL API Tracking

Tags: c#, .net, rest, api

I have tried adding the Service Reference to my Project but this is not working?

https://api-eu.dhl.com/tracking

I am getting the following error when trying to add the Service Reference

```
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://api-eu.dhl.com/tracking'.
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was ''.
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

Comment: You need to register with DHL for this purpose, you can then get an API Key and have to pass this API key as part of the URL

Comment: I tried registering(in progress) but I see a Consumer Key and Consumer Secret. Any idea how I put these in a URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive that error because you pass a wrong key, and by reading the comments I see that you don't have an application registered yet.

The following headers are needed to consume DHL API endpoints.

```
'Accept': 'application/json',
'DHL-API-Key': 'ApiKeyHere'
```

There is a written sample in Python https://developer.dhl.com/api-reference/shipment-tracking#get-started-section%example-requests-to-the-api

If you need help with writing it in C#, you can follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39670617/5394806